# Gulp/Grunt read dynamic HTML field configuration

Tags: javascript, gulp, gruntjs

Let's say I have the following requirement.

I want to create HTML fields dynamically. Now the configuration of these fields would come from some external API in JSON format.
e.g. The config might say field type as "dropdown" and id as "dropdown_1"

How do I map this config to create my HTML fields dynamically without requiring much coding ? Can we use Gulp/Grunt for the same ?

Comment: do you want to populate this at run time or during build phase ?

Comment: Either options should be fine...As of now, I am just looking at ideas & see if it is possible to achieve such kind of things with Gulp/Grunt ?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-replace or https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-task